# How do I change or disable the annoying sound when the machine hibernates?

Tags: windows-7, hibernate, system-sounds

Whenever my machine hibernates or awakens from hibernation, it plays the `chimes.wav` sound in a most annoying manner.

I've looked everywhere in the control panel and cannot see how to turn this off or change it.  "*Play Windows Startup sound*" is not checked, and I even went so far as to select the *No Sounds* scheme from the System sounds control panel.  While this did stop all other system sounds (some of which I want), it still did not stop the hibernation sounds!

How can I defeat this pestilence?

It's a  Windows-7 Pro, ASUS laptop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this functionality is built into Windows, so there's probably a third-party app running that is responsible for the annoying sounds.  Perhaps some of that lovely shovelware that OEMs so love to install...

For example, [the *Boingo Wi-Fi* utility](http://www.windowsvc.com/bbs/board.php?bo_table=windowsvc&wr_id=2504&page=2120), that ASUS installs to run at startup, will do this. (Note from the OP, this was it.)

Do you see anything non-standard in Task Manager? Are there any custom control panels installed by your hardware vendor? For example, I remember that Lenovo installed a "ThinkPad Power Manager" application that supported similar nonsense.

Try closing and uninstalling stuff until your machine is faster than it was before, stops beeping, or both. Or more drastically, wipe out the drive and begin fresh by re-installing Windows.

Comment: Note that reinstalling windows is not a good option because the OEM install restores all the "shovelware" too!

Comment: Revisited all the default-installed cruft that I'd removed yesterday.  Turns out that it was a "Boingo" Wifi-sniffing utility that ASUS had running upon startup.